# Power BI / DAX Countax with two conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is doing my head in and need help. I have simple countifs to do but in Power BI. Basically I want to count how many items are with status C and how many with C.

My data looks like that:

```
WP  SUB_WP  STATE
a   1       O
a   2       C
b   3       O
b   4       O
c   5       C
c   6       C
```

And desired results are:

```
WP  SUB_WP  STATE   COUNT O COUNT C
a   1       O       1       1
a   2       C       1       1
b   3       O       2       0
b   4       O       2       0
c   5       C       0       2
c   6       C       0       2
```

In excel is dead simple `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C, "=O")` and `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C, "=C")`

How to get the same in Power BI please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These particular counts can be done as follows:

`Count O` measure (counts the number of `O` States for a particular `WP`):

```
count O = 
  VAR res = CALCULATE(
              COUNTROWS(data),
              FILTER( 
                  ALLEXCEPT(data, data[WP]), 
                  data[STATE] = "O"
              )
)
RETURN IF( ISBLANK(res), 0, res)
```

`Count C` measure (counts the number of `C` States for a particular `WP`):

```
count C = 
  VAR res = CALCULATE(
              COUNTROWS(data),
              FILTER(
                 ALLEXCEPT(data, data[WP]), 
                 data[STATE] = "C"
              )
)
RETURN IF( ISBLANK(res), 0, res)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Such a simple and clean solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your desired output in PoweBI

[image]

How did I do that? I created 2 new columns with `Count C` and `Count O`

```
Count O = IF(LOWER('Table'[STATE])="o";1;0)
Count C = IF( LOWER('Table'[STATE])="c";1;0)
```

and in Values for table Summarize new Column `Count O` and `Count C`

Comment: That doesn't look like OP's desired result.  OP wants 'Count O' and 'Count C' tallied at 'WP' level of granularity, not at row level.